# Django -- How to have a project wide templatetags shared among all my apps in that project

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, tags

Second time asking more details ...

I'd like to have a project wide templagetags directory to have the common
tags used by all Apps, then each app can have their own tags if need so.

Let say that I have:

```
proj1/app1
proj1/app1/templatetags/app1_tags.py

proj1/app2
proj1/app2/templatetags/app2_tags.py

proj1/templatetags/proj1_tags.py

proj1/templates/app1/base.html
proj1/templates/app1/index.html
proj1/templates/app2/base.html
proj1/templates/app2/index.html
```

**Where:**

```
proj1/templates/app1/base.html
-----------
{% load proj1_tags %}
{% load app1_tags %}

proj1/templates/app1/index.html
-----------
{% extends "base.html" %}

proj1/templates/app2/base.html
-----------
{% load proj2_tags %}
{% load app2_tags %}

proj1/templates/app2/index.html
-----------
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Would this work? It didn't work for me. It can't find the proj1_tags to load.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I don't know if this is the *right* way to do it, but in my Django apps, I always place common template tags in a `lib` "app", like so:

```
proj/
    __init__.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        templatetags/
            __init__.py
            common_tags.py
```

Just make sure to add the `lib` app to your list of `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Comment: I usually name the app after the project: "project_core" - but same solution.

Comment: how you than call it in html files? Just `{% load common_tags %}`?

Comment: @andi: Yes, that's it.

Comment: The name of the module inside tempaltetags is the same as the package/application name (e.g. lib.py).

Comment: Don't know if this is the *right* way either, but the smartest solution I have come across while trying to manage that. It makes me realize that apps in django can be meta-apps in a way, not just corresponding strictly to a project functionality....

Answer (score 36):

Since Django 1.9, it is no longer necessary to create additional `common` app as others mentioned. All you need to do is to add a path to your project `templatetags` directory to the `settings.py`'s `OPTION['libraries']` dict.

After that, these tags will be accessible throughout your whole project. The `templatetags` folder can be placed wherever you need and can also have different name.

Customized example from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django):

```
OPTIONS={
    'libraries': {
        'myapp_tags': 'path.to.myapp.tags',
        'project_tags': 'project.templatetags.common_extras',
        'admin.urls': 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_urls',
    },
}
```

Comment: Just to make it clearer, in the template html where this tag is called one needs to `{% load project_tags %}` first before calling the tag normally using `{% common_extras %}`.

Comment: `All you need to do is to add a path to your project` can you elaborate on this part and give an example project structure showing the templatetags directory not inside of an app?

Comment: I seem to have got it working for a `templatetags` directory at the same level of `manage.py`.  Using `'mytest_tags': 'templatetags.mytest_tags'`. I have `__init.py__` inside of templatetags directory and also a python file named `mytest_tags.py`

Comment: Add a public app for all common templatetags and functions. This options works for me. Django version 2.17

Comment: OPTIONS is under TEMPLATES in Django 2.1.2

Answer (score 7):

Django registers templatetags globally for each app in `INSTALLED_APPS` (and that's why your solution does not work: *project* is not an *application* as understood by Django) — they are available in all templates (providing they was properly registered).

I usually have an app that handles *miscellaneous functionality* (like site's start page) and put templatetags not related to any particular app there, but this is purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 6):

This is the place where you place it in **settings.py**.

The first key('custom_tags' in this case) in 'libraries' should be what you want to load name in template.

---

**PROJECT STRUCTURE**

```
mysite
    - myapp
    - mysite
        - manage.py
        - templatetags
            - custom_tags.py
```

---

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': '....',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
            ],
            'libraries': {
                'custom_tags': 'mysite.templatetags.custom_tags',
            }
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: This post really helps! Django's official document always lacks real-world examples and file structure explanations.

Comment: what the manage.py doin there? u mean settings.py?

Answer (score -2):

Django works by App. They are refer in the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

I suggest to you to split everything related to a different app. For your templatetags problem, you could create an app called 'common_tags'. Then setup the INSTALLED_APPS settings to use it, and you'll be able to load your common tags from any templates like so:

```
{% load XXXX %}
```