# Menu shared by all applications in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've built a `menu` as a `templatetag` in Django>1.9.
The problem is that following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492671/2228912), I can't put the templatetag at the root of the folder, as I'm getting a:

`TemplateSyntaxError: 'menu' is not a registered tag library`

Below is the part of my `settings.py` that I've modified:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # Look for base template at root of project
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            # Look for base templatetags at root of project
            'libraries': {
                'project_tags': 'templatetags.menu',
            }
        },
    },
]
```

Even with an empty `menu.py` template tag like the one below I get the same error:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('menu.html', takes_context=True)
def menu(context):
    pass
```

Does `Django` support project-wide `templatetags` at all?

Comment: you have a "templatetags" folder? Alternatively you could use`{%include "menuTemplate"%}` in you templates...

Comment: could you provide snippet of the html file?

Comment: @hansTheFranz The `menu.py` is inside a `templatetags` folder at the root of the project.

Comment: @mateuszb the `templates/menu.html` is just a basic `ul` menu (nothing fancy).

Comment: @h4k1m OK, so you're loading project_tags with {% load project_tags %}, right?

Comment: @mateuszb Exactly then I call it inside the base.html using `{% menu %}`.

Comment: @h4k1m ok, so it looks like something wrong with the template tag itself

Comment: @mateuszb I don't think so, even with empty `menu.py` (see updated question) and `menu.html`, I still get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had it fixed by loading in my `base.html` template the module (i.e. `project_tags`) instead of the tag (i.e. `menu`), and then calling normally the tag `menu`:

So it's

```
{% load project_tags %}
...
{% menu %}
```

Instead of:

```
{% load menu %}
...
{% menu %}
```