# How can I refer to static variables across all of my HTML templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm just learning Django and Python and want to be sure I'm doing things the right DRY way and I'm sure there's a MUCH easier way to do this...

Right now, I have the following `base_template_tags.py` as it's own app (added into settings.py and loaded on the HTML template `{% load ... %}` that allows me to access the year as an HTML tag via `{% cd_year %}` and/or the email address as `{ cd_email }`.  It works... but it's a hack.

Is there a better way?

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)

@register.simple_tag
def cd_year():
    return datetime.now().year

@register.simple_tag
def cd_email():
    return 'pp@pp.com'
```

Comment: What about [`now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#now)?

Comment: oh, sorry.. i should have clarified... i have a bunch of constants that I'd like to access across the application... not just this one for the date.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext), not template tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you guessed, there is a much more easier way built-in to django:

```
{% now "Y" %}
```

#### Edit

As you mentioned in the comments that you want to share a *bunch of template tags* among all of your apps, you can override `libraries` dictionary and add your custom template tags there.

Read more about that in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django)

and for your templates:

```
{% load your_template_tags_file_name %}


{% cd_year %}
```

#### Edit 2

This is how the `TEMPLATES` part of your `settings.py` should look like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries': {      # <-----------
                'global_tags': 'template_tags.global_tags',
                'admin.urls': 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_urls',
            },
        },
    },
]
```

and your directory structure should be like:

```
<your_project_dir>
├── __init__.py
├── settings.py
├── template_tags
│   ├── global_tags.py
│   ├── __init__.py
...
```

the `global_tags.py` file should contain your template tag definition and registration, as:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.now().strftime(format_string)

@register.simple_tag
def cd_year():
    return datetime.now().year

@register.simple_tag
def cd_email():
    return 'pp@pp.com'
```

and for each template that's going to use those custom template tags:

```
{% load global_tags %}


{% cd_year %}
```

Comment: oh, sorry.. I would like to do this for a bunch of constants.. like {{ application_name }} , {{ contact_email }}, and the like.

Comment: So you want to define your all of your custom `template_tags` once and re-use them in all the apps?

Comment: @P'P' Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492671/9733868) answer; that's my preferred way of doing it.

Comment: Also from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django).

Comment: got it, that's pretty much what I'm doing now (added as a library in TEMPLATES in static.py as well as INSTALLED_APPS).  It works, but I was just curious if there was a such thing as a global context object or the like.  i.e. I moved these definitions to this template_tags bit to not have to add the values in the various views.  i had this before which had to be constantly repeated -

Comment: def contact(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'misc/contact.html',
        {
      'year':constants.cd_year,
        'email':constants.cd_email
        }
    )

Comment: i.e. I want to access these constants via {{ STATIC_VARIABLE_NAME }} rather than by calling the function {% FUNCTION_THAT_RETURNS_STATIC_VALUE %}

Comment: Well, if you shared those template tags among all the apps (with either your approach or using `libraries`), you have access to them **directly** in the templates (after loading it); as in `{% cd_year %}`; So you don't need a function `def contact...` to access them.

Comment: just tried.. just tried that, but got the following:

Comment: Invalid block tag on line 43: 'cd_name'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Did you load your template_tag at the top of your html template?

Comment: @register.simple_tag

Comment: Yes, you need to register them; But you should also ***load*** them in your html templates as well (`{% load base_template_tags %}`)

Comment: @P'P' if you can't get it working properly, please let me know to include a full example.

Comment: thanks, please do if you could.  I have it working like this, but it's still a function and not just a variable declaration.@register.simple_tag
def cd_email():
    return 'pp@pp.com'

Comment: Is this something that belong in a Context Processor?  and if so, how can I configure that?

Comment: right, but this handles everything as a function.  cd_year() is a function call and not a reference to the static variable.  That's what I was asking about a better way.  Also, {{ cd_year }} doesn't seem to come back with anything for me.  {% cd_year %} does however.

Comment: So what do you mean by a _better_ way? As I mentioned earlier, it's better to use django's default template-tags when it's possible (e.g. current year); but for other variables (either _static_ or _dynamic_) you should use template tags, or context processor (check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/433209/9733868)). and I make a mistake about `{{  cd_year}}`, it should be `{% cd_year %}`. thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: AWESOME!  Yes, exactly that.  Perfect!  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can used below code in .html

```
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% endblock %}
```

1. Create a new folder “static” in the root of the main project.
   Same level as the “templates” directory.
2. Add this code to your base template file (__base.html).

   {% load staticfiles %}
3. Use this to load the files.
4. Add this to your settings.py file.

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), 
     ]

**Create global context:**
You have create App inside context_processor.py file
In context_processor file written:

```
from app.model import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import user
def employee_processor(request):
    try:
        emp_obj= Employees.object.filter(user=request.user)
        return { ’employee’:emp_obj}
    except:
        user_obj=User.object.filter(id=request.user)
        return { ’employee’: user_obj}
```

Add your context processor in your setting py file:

```
TEMPLATES = [{
    # whatever comes before
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
             # whatever comes before
                   "your_app.context_processors.employee_processor",
        ],
    }
}]
```

Then you can used global variables in your HTML template

```
{{ employee }}
{{ employee.name }}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How can I get to the constants stored within those static files?  I'm really looking for the right place to define global constants.. such as `email` or the like